# Como executar uma classe Timer (sempre) na implantação?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Tenho um projeto não-Web e vou transformá-lo em um projeto Web usando o Spring MVC.

Hoje no meu método `static main` da minha classe principal, eu crio isso aqui:

```
    Exec.principalTimer = new Timer();
    Exec.principalTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new PrincipalTimerTask(), Exec.delay, Exec.interval);
```

A classe `PrincipalTimerTask` é do tipo `TimerTask`.

Como eu crio esse Timer no Spring já na implantação do projeto, sem ter que chamar url nenhuma e deixo ele rodando lá, como se fosse um serviço se eu não tenho um `public static main` no container Web?

---

Eu posso implementar a interface WebApplicationInitializer e criar o TImer já dentro do metodo onStartup dela.

Aqui da onde eu peguei a ideia
http://joshlong.com/jl/blogPost/simplified_web_configuration_with_spring.html

Comment: Aplicações Web têm um tratamento de estado diferente de aplicações console, com janelas ou serviços. Acho que você vai precisar, além da aplicação Web, de um serviço que fique chamando algo pela URL ou por outro meio em intervalos fixos. O nome técnico pra isso é Cron Job.

Comment: Você não pode usar o Quartz (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)?

Comment: Vou anotar aqui, o chato é tipo "mais um framework"... ahhah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar  [EventListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html) pode resolver seu problema, mas não é o ideal pois foi feito para executar determinada ação após um evento no sistema.

Se tratando de Spring você pode usar a anotação [@Scheduled](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html). Para habilitar o uso de Schedule você precisar usar a anotação  `@EnableScheduling` na sua classe de configuração do Spring.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringConfig {
}
```

Depois você deve anotar uma classe com `@Component` e no método que vai executar a tarefa você usa a anotação `@Scheduled`.

Usando fixedDelay a execução entre a última execução e a próxima é fixada **e uma execução só começa quando a outra termina**.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {
    System.out.println("Fixed delay task - " + System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
}
```

Usando fixedRate, **a próxima execução começa sem levar em consideração se a última terminou**

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
public void scheduleFixedRateTask() {
    System.out.println("Fixed rate task - " + System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
}
```

initialDelay, a tarefa vai ser executada depois do valor do intialDelay e depois seguir do tempo do fixedDelay.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, initialDelay = 1000)
public void scheduleFixedRateWithInitialDelayTask() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    System.out.println("Fixed rate task with one second initial delay - " + now);
}
```

Lembrando que todos os valores são em **milisegundos** e você também pode usar expressões cron

Para saber mais olhe a [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).
Fonte: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

Comment: Obrigado, vou ver melhor isso!

Comment: Adelmo é possivel extender Scheduled para ler de um arquivo de propriedade ao invés de ter um tempo fixo?

Comment: Não sei, mas vou pesquisar sobre. Por que você quer ler um arquivo de propriedades ao invés de configurar na própria anotação?

Comment: Então é para não ter q compilar cada vez que muda o interval do programa... Legal mesmo seria fazer ele dar um update no interval sem nem mesmo ter q parar a aplicação....

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250928/how-to-change-springs-scheduled-fixeddelay-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

A saida foi criar uma outra classe java qualquer anotada com @Component
e nela criar um metodo com essa assinatura..

```
 @EventListener
 public void onCreate(ContextRefreshedEvent e) {}
```

Esse método será executado assim que o spring ler todas as classes... Pelo menos foi isso que eu entendi